# Rational conjugation of elements of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, galois-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Two elements $x$ and $y$ of $G$ are said to be *rationally conjugate*, written $x \sim_{r} y$, if and only if $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$. Let $A$ be the set of all character values of $G$, 
and let $H$ be the Galois group of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(A)/\mathbb{Q}$.
 Is it true that the orbits of $H$ on conjugacy classes of $G$ are the same as the equivalence classes of $\sim_{r}$? Is there any proof or reference for this result?

Comment: The answer is yes, and I think this is clear, once you have shown that there is a well-defined action of $H$ on the conjugacy classes: Let $\varepsilon$ be a primitive $|G|$-th root of unity. Then the Galois group $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon)/\mathbb{Q}$ acts on the conjugacy classes, and $H$ is a factor group of $\Gamma $. It is well known and not difficult to show that the orbits of $\Gamma$ are the rational conjugacy classes. (c.f. Serre, Linear Representations of Finite Groups, §12.4.)

Comment: An earlier question which may be related to this one? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186581/rational-conjugacy-classes-of-finite-groups

Comment: @FriederLadisch, make this an answer!

Comment: In fact, this seems to be a duplicate of the question linked by @YemonChoi, only that the question here is formulated a little better. I have made my comment an answer to the old question, which already had an answer. I think this question can be closed as duplicate.